# setting environment variable on solaris crontab

Tags: shell, solaris, cron

Is there a way to set an environment variable directly in a crontab on solaris?

The behavior i want is for each script in my crontab to know a specific environment variable.  I want to avoid creating a setupEnvironment.sh script that all my scripts have to call.

Answer (score 0):

Yes no problem, i.e.

```
59 23 31 12 * { var="value" ; export var ;  /path/2/myProgram "${var}" ; }  > /tmp/myProgLogFile.txt 2>&1
```

OR (similar idea with ${var} now used being 'passed in the environment' of myProgram )

```
59 23 31 12 * { var="value" ; export var ; myProgVar="${var}" /path/2/myProgram ; }  > /tmp/myProgLogFile.txt 2>&1
```

These are slightly exaggerated examples. The key point being that you need to export var for it to be visible to any sub-processes that are being launched by the process group(er) ( `{ ... ; }` ) ... (Note that the closing ';' before the closing '}' is mandatory and that the error message if this is missing will not help you figure it out ;-) )

This is true for solaris and other old-line unixen where the /bin/sh is the borne shell (and not bash).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
* * * * * FOO=BAR your-command
```

should do it; it will invoke your-command with the environment variable `$FOO` set to `"BAR"`.  You'll have to do this for each command in your crontab; I don't think there's a way to do a global setting.